# Is there a way to remove certain strings from a JSON File using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

I want to replace a string in a JSON file with another string. All the solutions given use *json.load()* to do whatever necessary to a JSON File. But after trying a lot, I couldn't find a way to replace the string. I tried to read it the usual way Python reads files, using *open()* and *replace()* but that doesn't work with JSON files.

This is a part of the JSON file.

```
    "61" : {
      "a" : 0.0,
      "b" : 1.0,
      "c" : "[ 0, 1 ]"
    },
```

I want it to be:

```
    "61" : {
      "a" : 0.0,
      "b" : 1.0,
      "c" : [ 0, 1 ]
    },
```

This is what I tried with *open()* and *replace()*.

```
        fin = open(JSON_IN)
        fout = open(JSON_OUT, "w+")

        line_f = fin.readline()

        x1 = '"['
        while line_f:

            print(line_f)
            if x1 in line_f:
                line_f.replace('\"[', '[')
                line_f.replace(']\"', ']')
                fout.write(line_f)

            else:
                fout.write(line_f)
            line_f = fin.readline
```

I want the ***"[*** to be changed to just ***[***. Is there any way to do that using Python?

Comment: If it doesn't have quotes, it isn't a string.

Comment: Okay, agreed. Is there a way to remove them? I just want the quotes to be gone. @ScottHunter

Comment: better show your code

Comment: `text = text.replace('"[', '[').replace(']"', ']')` ? but it will change all `"[` `]"` in file. If you want to do in some places then you may have to work with every line separately.

Comment: @furas code for? I only have the JSON file. I tried using open() and replace() and tried to edit it like a normal file, but that doesn't do anything. Is that the code you wanna see?

Comment: did you assign result to variable? Did you save it ? Show code with `open()` and `replace()` and we will see what you made wrong.

Comment: @furas I want to take every line and check if a condition is true. Then only i need to change.

Comment: show your code. Don't expect that we will write all code for you. You will rather downvoted because you don't have code.

Comment: @furas there I have code. I don't mind the downvote. If you can solve the issue, please do. Thank you.

Comment: you forgot to assign result `line_f = line_f.replace('\"[', '[')`

Comment: you forgot `()` in last line `line_f = fin.readline()` but more popular is `for line_f in fin:` and you don't have to use `fin.readline()`

Comment: @furas But, I'm writing it into another file.

Comment: you don't need `\` if you put `"` inside `' '`

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable This is the error I'm getting. @furas

Comment: `replace()` doesn't change `line_f` - it returns new value. SO `line_f.replace('\"[', '[')` doesn't change it - you have to assign it again to variable `line_f = line_f.replace('\"[', '[')`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. @furas.

Comment: Use a context manager to handle the file.

Comment: Also the liberal use of `replace()` seems unsafe. Why not actually treat your value as JSON, and use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the lists from the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` doesn't change value in variable but it returns new value which you have to assing to variable

```
line_f = line_f.replace(...)
```

You don't need `\` if you put `"` in `' '` because it will search text with `\`

Code

```
fin = open(JSON_IN)
fout = open(JSON_OUT, "w+")

x1 = '"['

for line_f in fin:

    print(line_f)

    if x1 in line_f:
        line_f = line_f.replace('"[', '[').replace(']"', ']')

    fout.write(line_f)
```

---

if you want to change it in all file then you could even try

```
fin = open(JSON_IN)
fout = open(JSON_OUT, "w+")

text = fin.read()
text = text.replace('"[', '[').replace(']"', ']')
fout.write(text)
```